# Git merge different behavior on different computers

Tags: git

I have a repository with two branches pointing to the same position in tree:

- branchA (history: commit1, commit2, commit3)
- branchB (history: commit1, commit2, commit3)

I push "commit4" into "branchA":
`git fetch; git switch branchA; git pull; echo "aa" > newfile.txt; git add newfile.txt; git commit -m "added newfile.txt"; git push;`

My goal is to make branchB point to the same commit4 as branchA (so they are the same branch again) - I can rebase or merge:

rebase:
`git fetch; git switch branchB; git pull; git rebase origin/branchA; git commit; git push;`

merge:
`git fetch; git switch branchB; git pull; git merge origin/branchA; git commit; git push;`

Now my problem is following: If I use "merge" option result in the tree is the same as with rebase (both branches pointing to commit4, no new commit is created).

But when colleague uses the same "merge" commands, it results into new commit5 "Merge remote-tracking branch  'origin/branchA' into branchB" and tree is not simple one line (for those two branches) but instead it has two different lines with different commits:

- branchA (history: commit1, commit2, commit3, commit4)
- branchB (history: commit1, commit2, commit3, commit5)

Any idea how is it possible, that it only behaves like that from his computer and not from mine? Any suggestions, how to "fix" it?

Is it some flag or parameter that needs to be added to commit/push/merge commands to override some local git settings of his? Or is it version of git client?

In the Gitlab repository settings, we are allowing to push to both branches:

[image: repo settings]

Comment: Are you using the same git version?

Comment: Your colleague possibly has made some modifications and committed those to their local repository. Does both your Git HEADs have the same hash?

Comment: Is there a specific reason for the [GitHub] tag? This is all local, and at the very end, there's a mention of GitLab, but that is irrelevant for this problem anyway (you're comparing two local repositories; no server involved). (I think the [merge] tag can also go, given its description.)

Comment: It sounds like your merge was a fast-forward merge, and your colleague's wasn't. This is controlled via the [`merge.ff` setting](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-mergeff).

Comment: If the problem is solved, @tomas, either answer your own question or else delete the question; don't leave it hanging.

Comment: @tomas or else ask the individual who helped you out to write an answer, and then accept it. Either way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is simple as suggested in comments: "It sounds like your merge was a fast-forward merge, and your colleague's wasn't. This is controlled via the merge.ff setting.

- Benjamin W."

thanks Benjamin W.